# can predis hmget use array as parameter of multiple fields

Tags: php, redis, predis

can predis use array as 2nd parameter of hmget() to retrieve multiple fields on one go? e.g.
$client->hmget($key, $fields); //$fields is an array

Can it also accept many parameters of string as fields? e.g.:
$client->hmget($key, $field1, $field2, $field3);

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Predis supports two ways of passing multiple keys (or keys with values) for variadic Redis commands. The first one basically follows the same signature of commands as defined by the [Redis documentation](http://redis.io/commands), so using [HMSET](http://redis.io/commands/hmset) and [HMGET](http://redis.io/commands/hmget) as examples you will have:

```
$redis->hmset("hash", "field:1", "value:1", "field:2", "value:2");
$values = $redis->hmget("hash", "field:1", "field:2");
```

but you can also pass the list of keys and/or values as a single array argument:

```
$redis->hmset("hash", array("field:1" => "value:1", "field:2" => "value:2"));
$values = $redis->hmget("hash", array("field:1", "field:2"));
```

Choosing which one to use is really just a matter of preference.

Comment: Sorry @nrk, only the second approach works for me. The documentation https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis#hmget suggests its an array. The first approach returns a false. Is it dependent on a specific version?

Comment: @SanathBallal phpredis is not Predis, the question (and my answer) was related to the latter.

Answer (score 1):

From Predis repository

```
$redis->hmset('metavars', 'foo', 'bar', 'hoge', 'piyo', 'lol', 'wut');

$redis->hmget('metavars', 'foo', 'hoge', 'unknown'));
```

Comment: It's bad to vote down the question. What's wrong when you are not 100%sure and just want to clarify for the 1% uncertainty

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$pd =  $redis->hmget("regconfig" ,array("cont_mgr"));
print_r($pd);
```